# VPN client for linux machine + support Checkpoint gateway

Tags: linux, vpn, vpnc

Since Checkpoint Company not have a VPN client for Linux (Checkpoint VPN SNX R71 does not fit for us because this VPN requires changes on the gateway side )

I am trying to find if there is a VPN client (open source) or other VPN that can be installed on Linux machine and can connect to Checkpoint gateway

The following diagram describes what we want (we need to install VPN client on the Linux machine (My Linux machine)),

so with this VPN client we can connect (via SSH) to the target Linux machine

```
   My Linux machine     -->    firewall (checkpoint NGR75)  -->  Checkpoint gateway (FW)  -->  target Linux machine
```

Please advise what we can use as alternative?
Which VPN clients support checkpoint gateway (include VPN that not defined as open source) ,

Comment: Is the target VPN IPSec-, SSL-, PPP-, L2TP- or PPTP-based?

Comment: Why did you [cross post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126176/vpn-client-for-linux-machine-support-checkpoint-gateway) this so many places?

Comment: I will check that